# Probability problem that involves number theory

Tags: probability, number-theory

Let $k \in Z^+$. Assume integers 1, 2, 3, . . . , 3k+ 1 are written down randomly. Calculate the probability that at no time during this process, the sum of the integers is a positive integer divisible by 3?

Attempt: I am trying to approach this by finding the complement of what's being asked which is the number times the sum of the integers is divisible by 3. The sample space I think is $\prod_{i = 0}^{3k+1}(3(i)+1)!$ since that's I think the number of trees we can generate by doing this process.

I think my sample space is off. The right way is to
 figure out how many sequences can we have at some time i where $1 \leq i \leq 3k+1$ during the process. This is:

$(3k+1) +(3K+1)(3k) + (3k+1)(3k)(3k-1)+ ... + (3k+1)!$

I also have the feeling that this is done by using states. There are just three state where the sum can be at any time and these are: 0mod3, 1mod3 and 2mod3. We have to find all the possible ways we can reach the state 0mod3 somehow.

Comment: Are you considering a random permutation, or random drawing with possible repetition?

Comment: I think repetitions are not allowed and the order matters in the way I am doing it.

Comment: If we independently pick within a modified set $\{1, 2, ..., 3k\}$ each time, with replacement each time, then the probability of never seeing a sum multiple of 3 in $t$ steps is $(2/3)^t$. That is just because, every time, we are equally likely to pick a number that is eitehr $0, 1$, or $2$ (mod 3). [Just a minor comment][edit: @JMoravitz nice solution below]

Comment: If we were to ignore the numbers which are multiples of three for the time being and look at how the rest of the numbers are ordered, what do you notice?  Try arranging $k$ copies of $2$ and $k+1$ copies of $1$ while avoiding the partial sum being a multiple of three.  If you begin with a $1$, then what must the next number be?  A $1$ or a $2$?  How about the next number?  And the next?...  What if the first number was instead a $2$?  And the next?...  Now, how do we add back in the multiples of three into this?

Comment: Now... given a specific arrangement of $k$ copies of $0$, $k+1$ copies of $1$ and $k$ copies of $2$ avoiding any partial sum being a multiple of three, pick which multiple of three occupied each spot previously labeled $0$, pick which numbers one more than a multiple of three occupied each spot previously labeled $1$, etc...  Compare this to the number of equally likely ways that you can arrange the $3k+1$ terms.

Answer (score 2):

For the problem where repitition is not allowed, i.e. we are looking at permutations of the numbers $1,2,3,\dots,3k+1$

Looking at the numbers modulo3 for now, every arrangement will be of the form $$1.1.2.1.2.1.2.1.\dots2.$$

where those numbers which are multiples of three will be placed somewhere where the dots are (*not the first number of the sequence*)

The reason should be clear: if the first non-multiple of three is $1$mod3, the next non-multiple of three cannot be a $2$, else we will have a sub-sum that is a multiple of three.  Therefore, the second must be a $1$ as well.  Similarly, the next must be a $2$mod3 to avoid a sub-sum being a multiple of three again, and so on.  Alternatively, if the first non-multiple of three is $2$mod3, we will have it begin $221212121\dots$, but this would require one or two more numbers which are $2mod3$ than numbers which are $1$mod3, an impossibility.  Finally, it cannot start with a multiple of three for obvious reasons.

There are $\binom{3k}{k-1}$ ways to insert the $k$ copies of $0$ into the sequence above by using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) as there are $k$ 0's to place into $2k+1$ available spots.

Now, replacing the $1$'s with an arrangement of all of the numbers which are $1$mod3, replacing all of the $2$'s with an arrangement of the numbers which are $2$mod3, and similarly for the $0$'s, we have a sequence of the numbers $1,2,3,\dots,3k+1$ satisfying your conditions.

There are $(k+1)!,k!,$ and $k!$ ways to do this respectively.

There are then $(k+1)!k!k!\binom{3k}{k-1}$ ways you can arrange the numbers satisfying your desired conditions.  This is out of the $(3k+1)!$ equally likely arrangements, making the probability:

$$\frac{(k+1)!k!k!\binom{3k}{k-1}}{(3k+1)!}$$

Comment: why do you assume there will always a dot between two numbers?

Comment: @ElChavoDelOcho each dot represents a *potential* slot for multiples of three, some of these dots might not be used, some will be used several times.  Count how to place the multiples of three into the available slots using stars-and-bars.  Important to note is that there is no dot at the very beginning but there *is* a dot at the very end.

Comment: "but this would require one or two more numbers which are 2mod3 than numbers which are 1mod3, an impossibility". I think just one more is necessary not two.

Comment: Now that I think about it, It can start with two. It has to alternate after the first number but it doesn't have to be paired up.

Comment: @ElChavoDelOcho Do not forget that we are trying to arrange $1,2,3,\dots,3k+1$ and we have a total of $k+1$ numbers which are $1$mod3, $k$ numbers which are $2$mod3, and $k$ numbers which are $0$mod3.  If we were to start with a $2$, then we would (*ignoring zeroes*) have it as 221212121...21 or we would have it as 2212121...212.  In the first case, we have one more 2 than we have 1's, in the second case we have two more 2's than we have 1's.  In both cases, we do not successfully use each of $1,2,3,4,\dots,3k+1$ exactly once each.

Comment: From this, we learn that we can *not* in fact start with a number which is $2$mod3 and successfully avoid any subsum being a multiple of three.

Comment: If we were to start with two then we would have k-1 2s and k+1 1s, so at the end two 1s will remain. What is the problem with that?

Comment: In the sequence `2212`.  How many $2$'s?  How many $1$'s?  In the sequence `22121` how many $2$'s?  How many $1$'s?  Are there more $2$'s than $1$'s?  If we look at the case where $k=1$, i.e. arranging $1,2,3,4$, if we start with $2$, can we do it?  There are only six possible permutations starting with $2$... `2134,2143,2314,2341,...`  Do you see that they all fail?

Comment: "If we were to start with two then we would have **k** 2's and **k-1** 1's, so at the end two 1's will remain.  What is the problem with that?"  We need them to fit into our sequence somehow still since we wish to place *every* number from $1,2,3,4,\dots,3k+1$.  Putting the first of them at the end will give us a multiple of three since 2+2+1+2+1+2+1+...+ 2+1+1 adds up to a multiple of three.

Comment: What if we stop the sequence and don't take into account more. The condition still holds since up to that point the sum is still not a multiple of 3.

Comment: Why would you think we would be allowed to do that and stop early?  We are wanting to arrange **exactly** $k+1$ copies of $1$, $k$ copies of $2$ and $k$ copies of $0$ (*and may arrange the zeroes after the fact*).  We are specifically arranging this **exact** amount of each because this is what is necessary for the problem since when we arrange $1,2,3,\dots,3k+1$ we are in effect arranging $k+1$ numbers which are $1$mod3, $k$ numbers which are $2$mod3 and $k$ numbers which are $0$mod3.  We are using **every** number exactly once, and using all $3k+1$ numbers, not fewer than $3k+1$ numbers.

Comment: Because we want to keep track of the sum at any point in the process as we place the numbers on the table one by one. "calculate the probability that at no time during this process", so it can be the sum up to a time x. It doesn't have to be at the end where all the numbers have been drawn I think.

Comment: "*At no time during the process*" I.e. arrange **all** $3k+1$ numbers.  "*at no time*" means the sum of the first number is not a multiple of three as well as the sum of the first two numbers is not a multiple of three, as well as the sum of the first three is not a multiple of three... as well as the sum of the first n numbers is not a multiple of three... as well as the sum of the first 3k+1 numbers is not a multiple of three.  All $3k+1$ of those conditions must be simultaneously met.  We do in fact arrange all $3k+1$ numbers, and we may not "stop early."

Comment: I am still confused XD, so we should take into account the sequence '2' because at that time the sum is not divisible by 3, so it's still in the space we want to count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70304/discussion-between-jmoravitz-and-elchavodelocho).

Answer (score 1):

JMoravitz gives nice comments above that lead to a great solution to the permutation-based problem.  The repetition-based problem is also interesting and I give some details on that:

Suppose every step $t \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ we independently pick a number uniform over $\{1, ..., M\}$, where $M \geq 3$ is a positive integer. What is the probability that the sum process is never a multiple of 3 during $t \in \{1, ..., T\}$?

Case 1:  If $M$ is a multiple of 3, the answer is $(2/3)^T$ since we are equally likely to pick a number that is 0, 1, or 2 (mod 3).

Case 2: If $M$ is not a multiple of 3, then we can define $p_i$ as the probability of picking a number that is $i$ (mod 3). So we can easily find $p_0, p_1, p_2$.  Then we can model the problem as a 3-state Markov chain with states $0, 1, 2$ being the current mod-3 sum.